# Local minima of a nonlinear optimization problem

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Consider the following non-linear optimization problem:
$${min}_c\left(\sum_{i=1}^nc_ix_i-7\right)^2$$

1. How can we determine the number of local minima points that this optimization problem has?
2. Is there also a way to find them?

Comment: please mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

The problem is convex and therefore has a unique minimum value. All $c$ that satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i=7$ (obtained from setting the derivative to $0$) solve the optimization problem. This is a linear system that has either $0$, $1$ or $\infty$ solutions.

Comment: Thanks! But how do you know that it is convex?

Comment: @Katy would the second derivative test be of help?